# Simultaneous assignment to a numpy array

Tags: python, sql, numpy, multiprocessing

I have a data structure which serves as a wrapper to a 2D numpy array in order to use labeled indices and perform statements such as

```
myMatrix[ "rowLabel", "colLabel" ] = 1.0
```

Basically this is implemented as

```
def __setitem__( self, row, col, value ):
  ... # Check validity of row/col labels.
  self.__matrixRepresentation[ ( self.__rowMap[row], self.__colMap[col] ) ] = value
```

I am assigning the values in a database table to this data structure, and it was straightforward to write a loop for this.  However, I want to execute this loop 100 million or more times, and iteratively retrieving chunks of values from the database table and moving them to this structure takes more time than I would prefer.

All of the values I retrieve from the database table have different (row,column) pairs.
Therefore, it seems that I could parallelize the above assignment, but I don't know if numpy arrays permit simultaneous assignment using some sort of internal locking mechanism for atomic operations, or if it altogether prohibits any such thought process.  If anyone has suggestions or criticisms, I would appreciate it.  (If possible, in this case I'd prefer not to resort to cython or PyPy.)

Answer (score 2):

Parallel execution at that level is unlikely here. The global interpreter lock will ruin your day. Besides, you're still going to have to pull each set of values out of the database sequentially, which is quite possibly going to dwarf the in-process map lookups and array assignment. Especially if the database is on a remote machine.

If at all possible, don't store your matrix in that database. Dedicated formats exist for efficiently storing large arrays. HDF5/NetCDF come to mind. There are excellent Python/NumPy libraries for using HDF5 datasets. With no further information on the format or purpose of the database and/or matrix, I can't really give you better storage recommendations.

If you don't control how that data is stored, you're just going to have to wait for it to get slurped in. Depending on what you're using it for and how often it gets updated, you might just wait for it once, and then updates from the database can be written to it from a separate thread as they become available.

(Unrelated terminology issue: "CPython" is the standard Python interpreter. I assume you meant that you don't want to write an extension for CPython using C, Cython, Boost Python, or whatever.)

Comment: Fantastic, thanks for the information on HDF5, which I was unaware of.  Just to make sure, and since other readers may be asking the same question -- can a HDF5 file created through one process be simultaneously read from and/or written to by another processes (since true multithreading isn't possible in cPython, and multiprocess is how I am computing results to store in a temporary database)?  (Also, thanks for the terminology fix - I mistakenly typed cPython when I meant cython.)

Comment: @J.B.Brown The manual suggests that as long as you're using a fairly normal (non-networked, non-parallel) filesystem, the access will be coherent. At the very least you should be able to get away with one writer + many readers.